# How search all text within django cms plugins

Tags: django-cms

I would like to find all instances of a string throughout my entire Django CMS site. I imagined I would find a database table containing the text of all the Text Plugins that I can search through.

I also want to replace the string with a different string, but main issue is just finding where this is stored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text content of the Text Plugins is stored in table `djangocms_text_ckeditor_text`

And then I was able to use `replace()`:

```sql
UPDATE djangocms_text_ckeditor_text
SET body = replace(body, 'foobar', 'fizzbuzz')
WHERE body like '%foobar%'
```